# How to create HTreeMap with case insensitive key?

Tags: mapdb

I have created HTreeMap with the following syntax but how should I specify case insensitive on the key. if there is a entry in the map with the key TOMAS, the method contains should return true when checked with string tomas.

```
HTreeMap<String, String>p_LocalMap=p_DB.createHashMap("Map1")
        .keySerializer(Serializer.STRING)
        .valueSerializer(Serializer.STRING)
        .make();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need new Serilizer with HashCode, Equals and Compare methods overriden.

Comment: same goes for BTreeMap as well? I have extended implementation for SerializerString and overriden compare method which does case insensitive comparison. Do I need to override equals and hashCode in this case?